# algorithm2e missing document mystery

Tags: packages, installing, algorithm2e

I am trying to use the `algorithm2e` package. I downloaded the package from CTAN and verified that I can typeset its own documentation (`algorithm2e.tex`).  I then try to write my own document that uses `algorithm2e`, as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

This TeX file is in the same directory as all the `algorithm2e` files that I copied from the web. I blew away all the `aux` files and other temporaries.

I get `Latex error: Missing documentSee the LaTeX manual...` etc.  I have tried this under TeXWorks, TeXShop, and Texmaker on a Mac Book Pro, all with the same results. I have read the detailed log and output of TeX trying to figure out what TeX thinks is missing, and I haven't found it.  Every other document I have tried to typeset works out ok.

If I take out the `\usepackage{algorithm2e}` command, everything is ok.  I also have had no trouble using many other packages, such as

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{noindent}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsbsy,comment,pifont}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

All ok.  The only one that seems to cause problems is `algorithm2e`, and only in my OWN document. To reiterate, it works great when typesetting its own documentation. I tried putting the following in every position in that block of usepackage commands

```
\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

it didn't matter where I put it, it generates the same error.

I've boiled this down into the smallest example I can make and I'm stumped.

Comment: Is there a reason that you didn't install that package via your TeX distribution? Or put the files into your `localtexmf` folder and refreshed the database?

Comment: This still does look like you're not putting your `.tex` file in the correct folder. By the way, you can put relative and absolute paths to a `\usepackage` quite like in an `\input`, e.g. `\usepackage{../algorithm2e}`, `\usepackage{algorithm2e/algorithm2e}` or `\usepackage{D:/myfu/nnypath/to/algorithm2e}`.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to the MWE and get the correct error message (probably `Missing \begin{document}`) and also the `.log` file to see the position of the error message (line number, what happened before).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel that isn't really supported (and will generate warnings from ProvidesPackage that the package names don't match)

Comment: Did you not forget to run `texhash` after installing the file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Quite right, too. I've just tested it with his MWE and was surprised it worked. For a official package there shall not be the need to this anyway.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem; the reason and the solution are included in my answer.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I did at first put the files in the localtexmf directory, then copied them to my application directory when that didn't work so as to cover the case that there was something wrong with the dependency search-path mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `relsize` package (internally loaded by `algorithm2e`); the former package is incompatible with the AMS document classes; processing the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

produces the exact problem mentioned in the question; the process ends with many warnings and the obtained .pdf is the following:

[image]

To prevent this from happening, load the `algorithm2e` package with the `norelsize` package option, as in:

```
\usepackage[norelsize]{algorithm2e}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[norelsize]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps the [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package could be of interest for you (it provides many possibilities to customize the layout of algorithms) to be used instead of `algorithm2e`.