# What's wrong with usepackage{algorithm2e}?

Tags: algorithm2e, overleaf

I am using a journal template to write a paper, but when I add

```
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
```

to it, it will automatically collapse with error like

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty:220:
Runaway argument?
{10}
Paragraph ende
d before \@tempb was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.220 \@tempa\small
```

What's wrong with it? How do I solve it?

Note that the package `algorithm2e` is needed in my paper.

My code is in https://www.overleaf.com/5851896cgssfm

`Main.tex`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathrsfs,makecell}          % Enable this line and disable the
                               % preceding line to obtain a two-column
                               % document whose style resembles the
                               % printed Automatica style.


\usepackage{graphicx}          % Include this line if your
                               % document contains figures,
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}     % or this line, depending on which
                               % you prefer.
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[subnum]{cases}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\allowdisplaybreaks 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frontmatter}
 \title{Test
 \vspace{-3.5ex}
 \thanksref{footnoteinfo}}

 \thanks[footnoteinfo]{}

 \author[li]{Wangyan Li}
 %\corauth[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: +86 21 55271299; fax: +86 21 55271299.}

 \address[li]{Business School, University of Shanghai for Science and Technology, Shanghai, China.\vspace{-1.5ex}}


 \begin{keyword}
 \end{keyword}

 \vspace{-1.0ex}
 \begin{abstract}
In this paper,
 \end{abstract}
 \end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

`autart.cls` (too big to post, please find it on https://www.overleaf.com/5851896cgssfm)

Thanks!

Comment: There's no code at the link you give…

Comment: Can't you add it to your post?

Comment: Please post a minimal example. For your question to be useful to others, the code causing the problem needs to be here unless you plan to maintain the buggy version indefinitely at that link. Moreover, people are more inclined to answer questions they can see all at once. Especially since I always assume a link means the OP has just posted *everything* with no attempt at minimisation - and who wants to wade through the entire mess of somebody else's buggy document?

Comment: there's an unrelated bug in `algorithm2e`; see the brief discussion in thd chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31581522#31581522 .  this may or may not be affecting your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Clicking on "PROJECT" in Overleaf's top bar will display the file list; the file `autart.cls` can then be viewed.)

Sounds related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75436/algorithm2e-missing-document-mystery), where `relsize` isn't compatible with `amsart.cls` (and probably `autart.cls` as well.)

Adding the `norelsize` option to `algorithm2e` gets rid of this error, but then you'd get another error:

```
Error: Command \algorithm already defined.
          Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Check in `autart.cls`, and you'll indeed see it already defines its own `algorithm` environment.

So it does look like `algorithm2e` isn't compatible with this journal document class!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I found if we replace the package `algorithm2e`by `algorithm`, it works fine.